# OpenCV: Remove background noise and increase signal strength

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to OpenCV and tried multiple things but still have some problems.
I have images like this:

[image]

In the center there is a cluster (hard to see). I want to find those clusters and count them. I use `cv2.findContours` for this and this already works very good for images where this clusters have a good brightness and the background noise is not too strong.

With images like this, where the cluster is very dark or images where the background noise is very strong and looks very similar to the actual cluster, i have problems detecting them.

So what I would like to do now is remove the background noise, so that only the clusters are left. Then I could increase the brightness of the image and (I think) it should be easier to identify those clusters.

The background noise can very a lot! The image above is a sample, where there is not that much background noise, but it can be a lot worse.
I have images where I know, that there are no clusters in it (negative control). Everything in there is just the background-noise. So my idea was to find the dominant color in this negative control:

```
from skimage import io
def getDominantColor(image):
        a = io.imread(image)[:, :, :-1]
    
        colors, count = np.unique(a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True)
        return colors[count.argmax()]
```

The dominant color should be the background noise.
And then subtract this dominant color from the images who has clusters in it:

```
def substract(image, dominant):
    cells = cv2.imread(image)
    cells = cells[:, :, 2]
    cells = cv2.subtract(cells, dominant)
```

This code is not working though... :) But besides that, I would like to know if you guys think this is the right direction for this kind of problem?

So in short, I would like to remove the background noise, so that only the information i'm interested in stays in the image.
Background noise can very a lot, and I have images where I know that only the background noise is in there and nothing else.

Thank you very much for any hint you can give me!
Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another variation from my previous solution in Python/OpenCV.

```
 - Read the input
 - Stretch to full dynamic range
 - Convert to gray
 - Threshold
 - Blur
 - Threshold again
 - Get the largest contour
 - Draw the contour outline on the stretched image
 - Extract the contour region from the stretched image and place it on a black background
 - Save the results
```

Input:

[image]

- Read the input
- Stretch to full dynamic range
- Apply morphology to clean the image
- Convert to gray
- Otsu threshold
- Get the largest contour
- Draw the contour outline on the stretched image
- Extract the contour region from the stretched image and place it on a black background
- Save the results

Stretched image:

[image]

Gray image:

[image]

Final threshold image:

[image]

Result 1:

[image]

Result 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV/Skimage

```
 - Read the input
 - Stretch to full dynamic range
 - Apply morphology to clean the image
 - Convert to gray
 - Otsu threshold
 - Get the largest contour
 - Draw the contour outline on the stretched image
 - Extract the contour region from the stretched image and place it on a black background
 - Save the results
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure


# read image
img = cv2.imread('dark_image.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# stretch dynamic range
stretch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255))

# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (101,101))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(stretch, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(morph,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
#thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]\
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw contour on stretched image
result1 = stretch.copy()
cv2.drawContours(result1, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), 1)

# draw region on black background
contour = np.zeros((stretch.shape[:2]), dtype=np.uint8)
result2 = np.zeros_like(stretch)
cv2.drawContours(contour, [big_contour], 0, 255, -1)
result2[contour > 0] = stretch[contour > 0]

# save result
cv2.imwrite("dark_image_stretch.jpg", stretch)
cv2.imwrite("dark_image_morph.jpg", morph)
cv2.imwrite("dark_image_gray.jpg", gray)
cv2.imwrite("dark_image_threshold.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("dark_image_result1.jpg", result1)
cv2.imwrite("dark_image_result2.jpg", result2)

# view result
cv2.imshow("stretch", stretch)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
cv2.imshow("threshold", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result1", result1)
cv2.imshow("result2", result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Stretch to full dynamic range image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned image:

[image]

Gray image:

[image]

Thresholded image:

[image]

Contour outline on stretched image:

[image]

Contour region from stretched image on black background:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This looks very intersting. I was just trying it out but I get the following error:

 gray = cv2.cvtColor(morph, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
...
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)

Do you maybe know what the problem is? I tried COLOR_BGRA2GRAY as well, same error

Comment: Probably an OpenCV version issue. It works fine for my OpenCV 3.8 and Python 3.7. What versions are you using? What is the dtype of your input image? `print(img.dtype)`.   As a guess, try `cv2.cvtColor(morph.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` or enCV version issue. It works fine for my OpenCV 3.8 and Python 3.7. Try `cv2.cvtColor((255*morph).astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: +1. could you explain the morphology part a little bit? I was working on something similar recently, I couldn't come up with something other than blurring which is kinda primitive. I mean why you chose to do what you did etc.

Comment: The morphology close will merge your center green better and the open will remove small light green dots. You can see the effects if you put imshow after the close. For removing small objects morphology often is more effective than blurring. The close is a dilate followed by an erode. The open is an erode followed by a dilate.

Comment: @fmw42 I played now a little bit with it (your suggestion for the fix worked) but this really takes a long time. This above is just a sample image. the original ones are 9000x9000 pixels. The calculation takes several minutes... Which would be too long for my usecase. Do you maybe have an alternative idea? What do you think of using a histogram, finding the most dominant color and then remove this one. Then I would increase the intensity of  the remaining colors. Maybe this would not be as exact as your approach, but 100% correctness is also not required in my case.

Comment: I do not think subtracting the dominant color will work. But you certainly can try.  I have posted another variation that might work faster.